# After migrating from App Engine Java 8 to Java 11 what local development and unit testing tools work well?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am reviewing the [migration path from Java 8 to Java 11 on Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/java-differences#datastore), in the past the GAE environment offered [excellent unit testing support](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/localunittesting) and a [local development environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-local-server).

But in the new Java 11 runtime, these seem to be missing, are they just not ready yet, or are they not coming to this new runtime?

The [testing page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/testing-and-deploying-your-app) says:

> To test your application's functionality before deploying, run your application in your local environment with the development tools that you usually use.

That seems to punt the question back to the user - but when deploying to GAE having local runtime emulation for development and unit testing is really important. If it's not ever coming to Java 11, what's the best/right way to actually develop and test a Java 11 runtime GAE app?

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research, the GAE local development environment for Java 8 is part of the standalone App Engine SDK and [has been deprecated.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download#appengine_sdk)

It doesn't look to me like a similar tool set will come for Java 11. At least for now.

I would say that for developing, as suggested in the Docs you referenced, you can use whatever development server of your preference.

As for unit testing.  Because of how unit tests should be designed and implemented, it is actually best not to rely on other software to simulate the GAE behavior. Instead, mocks and stubs should be used to provide inputs to the tested modules that should make them return the response that is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Their default local environment and gae runtime was based on Jetty. Since the Java 11 runtime you now need to pick your own application server which could be Jetty, Spring boot, Quarkus, Helidon or many others.

I picked the Grizzly HTTP server, as I wanted to use Jersey (the default JAX-RS implementation) and [their example](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/getting-started.html) used Grizzly.

I wrote a blog post about how I made it work on Google App Engine:
https://medium.com/@Leejjon_net/migrate-a-jersey-based-micro-service-to-java-11-and-deploy-to-app-engine-7ba41a835992

If you want tests to work, I fixed the tests in the sample of my blog in this tag:
My full Java 11 sample with just one http request that can run locally and on app engine has a sample unit test:
https://github.com/Leejjon/SimpleJerseyService/tree/1.1.1

Comment: thanks @leejjon for the response, I was wondering more about how to emulate the environment such as the datastore (firestore) or cloud tasks - but perhaps everyone just uses a development project in the cloud remotely from local dev environments for those services? In unit tests these can be mocked if there's not emulation available. Is that what you do?

Comment: In my project I use https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators/ to run locally. I didn't migrate to the firestore API yet. For unit tests I would mock the data from the datastore/firestore, but for integration tests you could run the emulator and make your test connect to that (possibly in a docker container if you don't want to install gcloud on the build server). For my hobby project I didn't do that.